# how can i C# application call a java application

Tags: c#, java, com+

can a C# application call a java application.

for example in C#

```
public int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    return // call java function to do the sum
}
```

then in Java will have a function do the actual sum

```
public int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

will COM+ help??

Thanks

Comment: I had tried that before, it doesnt work... didnt convert into dll successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could try:

1. [Expose the Java as a Jax-Ws web service](http://jxs.me/2010/05/12/simple-web-service-jax-ws/).
2. Use .NET's `svcutil.exe` against it to [generate a c# client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905.aspx)
3. Use the c# client to call Sum

Answer (score 1):

I have never used IKVM myself but I do know people that used it successfully.

Anyway, have you tried the following options:

- Use [jacob](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) : you can expose your java classes as COM objects that can be consumed by NET code.
- Use [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/)

Best

Adriano